# How do I load a texture from a config file?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am attempting to write a game for Android.

I want to load an openGL texture from a config file but I only know how to do it via using the R.drawable class.

So I have the following code

```
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.texturetest);
            gl.glGenTextures(1,textures,0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,bitmap,0);
```

So the question is how do I decode the bitmap using a string (retrieved from a config file) for the name rather than `R.drawable.texturetest`
ie the config file would look roughly like this

```
robot_texture=texturetest
```

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapFactory` has other methods that should work for this purpose.

- `decodeFile`, if you have a plain filename for the bitmap.
- `decodeStream`, which takes an `InputStream` as the argument. That should work well in combination with `AssetManager.open` (which returns an `InputStream`) if you store your bitmaps in the assets instead of in the resources.

Comment: Non of these work if the file is stored in the resource directory though do they?

Comment: Probably not. Any reason why you couldn't store them in the assets directory? If you want to get a resource by name, there's a `Resources.getIdentifier` method. So the whole thing might be as simple as `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, ...))`.

Comment: Is there any benefit performance wise to using the resources directory over assets over assets? Or is the named resources the only benefit?